# $AB$, $AC$ and $DE$ are tangent to the circle, what is the perimeter of the triangle $ADE$?

Tags: geometry

The lines $AB$, $AC$ and $DE$ are tangent to the circle with center $O$, the points $D$ and $E$ respectively belong to the segments $[AB]$ and $[AC]$.

$| AB | = l$ and $| OB | = | OC | = r$.
[image]

what is the perimeter of the triangle $ADE$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a drawing, and call $\,M\,$ to the tangency point of $\,DE\,$ with circle $\,O\,$: Since tangents from the same point exterior to the circle have equal lengths, we get:

$$DB=DM\;,\;\;EM=EC$$

Thus, the perimeter of $\,\Delta ADE\;$ is  (spoiler!):

> $$AB-DB +DE +AE=(l-DB)+(DM+ME) +(l-EC)=$$$$=l-\color{red}{DB}+\color{red}{DM}+\color{green}{ME}-\color{green}{EC}+l=2l$$

Comment: Antonio , what is the value of DM and EM interms of l and r ?

Comment: got it cleared , thanks

Comment: But perimeter is AD + DE + AE . BUT AB-DB is AB , how can it account for permiter ?

Comment: D is point on extended AB and E is a point on extended AE ?

Comment: i will add a draw

Comment: yes without diagram it confuses.

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam: $$DB=DM\implies -DB+DM=0\;.\;\;ME=EC\implies ME-EC=0\ldots$$ so we **do not care** what these quantities are: they cancel!

Comment: But for triangle perimeter it is AD + DE + AE = (AB+BD) + (DM + ME) + (EC+ AC) = 2AB + 2DM + 2EC .where comes cancelling

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam, did you read my *whole* answer? For it you have to put your mouse point over the gray area to see what's written there (spoiler)...

Comment: ya diagram makes this clear . I thought it was ADE circumscribing the circle with tangential points B, M ,C . Thanks .

Comment: Ok. Anytime @HarishKayarohanam

Comment: Thanks for handling me with patience . I have upvoted your answer . +1

Comment: i 'd like to understand why the area is the same if $R$ and $BC$ don't change.

Comment: Well, the result is clear, and some geometry books even mention it as a theorem: with the given data, the area of triangle $\,\Delta ADE\;$ depends only on the length of (any of) the tangent from A to the circle, and equals twice this length. Of course, the length of cord $\,BC\,$ depends on where the vertex $\,A\,$ is wrt the circle and thus also on the length of the tangent lines, but as given you can see it all boils down to $\,l\,$ .

Comment: thx but it missing p=f(L/r)

Comment: @user52413, I've no idea what you wrote above: what is p, what is f...?

Comment: @DonAntonio p for perimeter et f for function.

Comment: Well, then $P_{\Delta ADE}=2l=f(l,r)\;$ . This function is constant in $\,r\,$ , though I'm not sure what that $\,L/r\;$ there means...

Comment: i was looking for something better than trigonometry $l=r*tan(\widehat{AOC}) , and P=2*r*tan(\widehat{AOC})$

Comment: My demonstration **only** uses basic euclidean geometry, though I wouldn't say that is "better" than trigonometry...and I can't understand the point of your formulas: do you want to add a **new** unknown $\,\angle AOC\;$ ?!

Comment: i don't know $AD/AB=DE/BC$ so $AD*BC/AB=DE$ and if $BC/DE=1$ then $AD =DE$ and $P =3*AD$

Comment: @user52413, I'm trying to understand what you mean but I can't: isn't my answer satisfactory? If it is not, why? Now you bring me some geometry stuff which I'm not sure how it is related with the answer I wrote to you...Is there anything you don't understand in my answer?

Comment: nevermind, i'll ask an another one.

Answer (score 1):

> *lemma:Let c be a Excircle of $\Delta ADE$ and has tangency point M on $DE$,then $AD+DM$ is semiperimeter of $\Delta ADE$.*

We have $DB=DM$ and $AB=l$.now with the above lemma,the perimeter is $2l$.

Comment: Edited, thanks.